# BreadCrumb Tag in PrimeFaces not Working

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation

i am not able to call the action method from p:breadCrumb which is dynamically created...
means when i cliked on p:menuitem in the breadcrumb it wont call my back() method in ManagedBean

and we are using primefaces3.4-snapshot jar

here my .xhtml

```
 <p:breadCrumb>
      <c:forEach items="#{pc_statusWiseRep.stackBeans}" var="path">
           <p:menuitem value="#{path.name}"  action="#{pc_statusWiseRep.backpath.id,path.lvl,path.name,path.slno}" update="form" />                                                 
     </c:forEach>
 </p:breadCrumb>
```

here is the method of back() in managed bean(session scoped)

```
public String back(String id, String lvl, String name, String slno) {
.....
}

List<StackBean> stackBeans = new ArrayList<StackBean>();
```

this is bean

```
public class StackBean {
String lvl = "";
String id = "";
String name = "";
int slno = 0;
..setters//getters
}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to invoke the `back` method in your bean (see my changes in `action`):

```
<p:breadCrumb>
      <c:forEach items="#{pc_statusWiseRep.stackBeans}" var="path">
           <p:menuitem value="#{path.name}"  
                       action="#{pc_statusWiseRep.back(path.id,path.lvl,path.name,path.slno)}" update="form" />                                                 
     </c:forEach>
 </p:breadCrumb>
```

Comment: i have tried what you have mentioned but its not working my p:menuitem <p:menuitem value="#{path.name}"  action="#{pc_statusWiseRep.back(path.id,path.lvl,path.name,path.slno)}" update="form" />

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error message? Are you positive the method back() is not called?

Comment: the method back() wasn't called